# Azure AD enterprise application provisioning

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim2

I am facing issues while provisioning Java application in Azure AD enterprise application. I have created SCIM api as per the azure documents but still I am getting below error.

Error code: SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementCredentialValidationUnavailable

Details: We received this unexpected response from your application: An HTTP/404 Not Found response was returned rather than the expected HTTP/200 OK response. To address this issue, ensure that the tenant URL is correct. The tenant URL is usually in a format like: https://<>/scim. If this does not resolve the issue, contact the application developer to ensure their SCIM endpoint conforms with the protocol https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.4.2 Please check the service and try again.

Comment: Could you please verify if the tenant URL is in this format: https://api.contoso.com/scim/ . Also, please check if the account that you are using has  all necessary tenant and API permissions

Answer (score 1):

You would need to ensure your response is formatted like in section 3.4.2 for the RFC

{
"schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"],
"totalResults": 0,
"Resources": [],
"startIndex": 1,
"itemsPerPage": 20
}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#response-3